# object_attachment and linking to an Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am posting to a user's stream successfully with the following JSON data (using the Facebook C# API, not that it matters, I think):

```
caption = String.Format("New album from {0}!", App.Current.AppTitle),
link = m_control.m_popup.Album.FacebookAlbumLink,
message = m_control.GetMessage(),
object_attachment = slideForCover.FacebookId,
```

Now, everything works as expected, except for one thing - the thumbnail, when clicked has one of two behaviors (the link when clicked works fine):

1. I get the picture the object_attachment is pointing to momentarily and then it dissapears, saying: "This content is currently unavailable".
2. I get the correct picture, but no commenting, no navigation, no anything.

What I want is, optimally, tapping the image to show me the beginning of the album and if that's impossible, I want tapping on the picture to bring me to that picture inside the album with full navigation (so no error etc).

Edit 1 - More information:
I have an example that shows the issue coded with the Facebook C# API. [Download here](http://speedy.sh/JRCba/TestPostAlbum.zip). You need to edit MainPage.xaml.cs to put some test app id and you need to have a c:\temp\pic.jpg file available for uploading.

Comment: How recently was the album/photo created? If you run this referring to an album/picture that's existed for a while, do you get the weird behaviour?

Comment: Album was just created. Posting links to older albums seems to exhibit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. It's definitely a bug somewhere on FB.

Why not post a link to the photo (using the link param)? This seems to work well on Timeline (shows a big picture, with the popup working correctly), and bypasses the object_attachment issue.

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure I understand... I need the link to give me the album - not the picture....

Comment: Try setting the link param on your post to the album url (http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=...). It seems to get really good treatment on Timeline (large photo, link to album). Much nicer than the object_attachment param.

Comment: I do that. All I get is a screenshotless link like any other link you would publish.

Comment: @Shahar: If you also set the `picture` field associated with the `link` field, you'll get the preview image. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/